# Multiple condition postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with three columns cola, colb, colc, containing a positive integer (which can be null though). I would like to make an INSERT INTO a new table if cola, colb, or colc is not null, in such a way that if none of them are null, then I will have three new entries inserted, and if only two of them the corresponding two new entries.

This syntax is working, but I am looking for a possible simpler way to do :

```
INSERT INTO new_table select 'cola' where table.cola > 0;
INSERT INTO new_table select 'colb' where table.colb > 0;
INSERT INTO new_table select 'colc' where table.colc > 0;
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: So, do you need insert into newtable every cola, colb, or colc values, when they are NOT NULL ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Yes, if we understand each other correctly, it is that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple rows (using `UNION`) and add them in one `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO 
    new_table (
        SELECT 'cola' WHERE table.cola > 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'colb' WHERE table.colb > 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'colc' WHERE table.colc > 0
    );
```

Comment: Why `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? `UNION` will remove duplicate values.

Comment: @OtoShavadze You're right - `UNION ALL` is a better choice and it's faster. I've edited my answer, thanks for pointing this out.